# UI blocks after starting a new thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm starting a new thread (drawing ellipses on canvas) on button click, but after that all Window and buttons are locked. I've looked through simular threads on this site but it did't help (sorry for my english)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;

namespace WpfПотоки
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //PriorityCombo.Items.Add(1);
            //PriorityCombo.Items.Add(2);
            //PriorityCombo.Items.Add(3);
            //PriorityCombo.Items.Add(4);
            //PriorityCombo.SelectedIndex = 3;

            PriorityCombo.Items.Add(ThreadPriority.Highest);
            PriorityCombo.Items.Add(ThreadPriority.AboveNormal);
            PriorityCombo.Items.Add(ThreadPriority.Normal);
            PriorityCombo.Items.Add(ThreadPriority.BelowNormal);
            PriorityCombo.Items.Add(ThreadPriority.Lowest);
            PriorityCombo.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }

        public void Circle()
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var e = new Ellipse();
                    e.Height = 25;
                    e.Width = 25;
                    var brush = new SolidColorBrush(ColorPicker.SelectedColor);

                    var y = rand.Next(25, (int)(Canvas1.ActualHeight - 28));
                    var x = rand.Next(25, (int)(Canvas1.ActualWidth - 28));

                    Canvas.SetTop(e, y);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(e, x);
                    e.Fill = brush;
                    Canvas1.Children.Add(e);
                });
            }            
        }


        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var thread=new Thread(Circle);
            thread.Priority = (ThreadPriority)PriorityCombo.SelectionBoxItem;
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you create new thread it is useless; you are using main thread only using `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Can you say what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: If you want your Circle method to not make UI hung, then make it 'async'. No need to use explicit Threading.

Comment: Well the aim was on each button click start a new thread that would draw (green, black etc) ellipses

Comment: But is it possible not to use Dispatcher.Invoke? The Canvas I draw on belongs to the main thread, and without Dispatcher.Invoke I get exception, sorry I'm new to all these threads stuff

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get a good book on WPF. You did it the "Windows Forms" way. That will only frustrate you. There are classes that will animate just about anything for you, but you have to know them and don't reinvent the wheel. Especially not if your wheel is not working. Don't try to switch to WPF with WinForms background without help. That won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new thread is grabbing the UI thread and adding many new elipses as fast as it gets. There is little the UI thread could do in the meantime. Your program will crash after about 65k iterations of your while loop anyway, because you are holding onto the brushes and windows does not have enough resources to hold more than 65k handles to brushes.

Whatever you want to do, this is not the way. Maybe you can describe what you want to achieve, so we can actually help you. The way you coded it, there is nothing we can do to make it work.